# Standalone Google App Script Invocation from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have refactored my bound GAS script into a standalone script (for re-use) and decoupled the google sheets specific calls. I would like to be able to invoke the standalone google app script from within a bound Google Sheets script, is there a way to do this?

Comment: As a "library".  All that is, is referring to another Apps Script project by it's ID number.  Use the "Resources" menu, and choose "libraries."  See this [link to Apps Script documentation - libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)  The other way to access the stand alone script is by making it an Add-on.